# Email not going into inbox, using apex_mail.send package

Tags: email, oracle-apex

I am now able to send e-mail messages using the apex_mail.send package. Unfortunately, all e-mail messages, go to spam folder. The emails have subject and body text too.
Is there anything I should add in the security?

Comment: That will depend on your specific e-mail provider and the spam filters that they use. In my experience this can be unique for each potential recipient, even when using the same provider; there is no "one fix for all" to keep messages from going to the Spam folder.

Comment: Impossible to answer. Make sure your recipients opted in to your email list (don't buy email lists somewhere). Make sure DKIM, DMARC, and SPF are set up; (have your mail server) DKIM-sign the emails. Format your emails correctly. Run your emails through spam assassin to get an idea what a spam filter thinks of them. Make sure your IP address has a good reputation. Get on the email feedback loop lists of the big email providers.